# Need a list of machine attributes to inventory and track

Tags: windows

We're evaluating helpdesk/ticketing/inventory management software. Does anyone have a list or a clean way of getting a list of all machine attribute types? I'm not looking to get the actual values, but rather a list of types. Such as processor, video card, mac address, IP, ect formulated for my working group.

Comment: A better question is "How much detail do you want?" -- Is PC/Mac, OS, Serial Number & who/what it's assigned to enough? If not, why do you *need* more detail (**NEED**, not **WANT** -- what will you be doing with it, etc.).  Sometimes simpler is better...

Comment: The goal here is to present the idea of coupling machine inventory with helpdesk/ticket management. Products like OCS Inventory and GLPI do this linking very well. However, I want to de-couple this list from any specific product like spiceworks. By listing all machine characteristics I can show the valuable data such as mac address linking to vulnerability scanner and video card to known bug databases.

Answer (score 2):

Can't Spiceworks pull that info?

http://www.spiceworks.com/

Comment: Matt, I'm reasonably certain this isn't a spam post of yours but it set off all the alarms; you've never posted before, skipped the 'how to answer' text and have used your first post to link to a product. Can you edit it with more explanation and consider this 'spam alert' next time please.

Answer (score 1):

The [Win32_*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394084%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) WMI Classes are in my opinion one of the easiest ways to get some pretty detailed information about a particular system, and it's really easy to knock up a .net program to gather and store information in a database.

The class names are pretty self explanatory about what the contain, but do be aware that some classes have members that exist only in later Operating Systems, and depending on the computer not all members will return a value (or they will return something outrageously stupid).

Answer (score 0):

yes spiceworks can do it, but most network inventory software requires you installing an agent on the hosts before information is returned, let alone dealing with switches and router info.

You could network scan to return basic information back. I think a network scan will return quite a bit of information for you to provide basic info.

I would look at using as a trial, spiceworks, MS system centre, Manage Engine Asset Explorer, SysAid (popular) and many many others. I have mentioned these as I have used all and prefer system centre over anything else. It works well.

Sorry I think I mis-understood your questions.

If you download Manage Engine Asset explorer, from memory they have a template that you could use and MS System has templates also. I think this is what you were asking?